# Rails 3.0 Devise reset Password by answering a question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, passwords, devise

I am using devise with rails 3. In user model I have created fields for the question and answer to that question.

I want to know How I can implement forget password in following logic:

1. On forget password page User enters the Username
2. On Next step application should displays the question stored in db.
3. User answers the question and app matches the answer if answer is matched with values stored in db.
4. It redirects to edit password page where password can updated.

I tried to override password  controller of devise but got stuck.

Thanks for help in advance.

Note: I am new to rails and its my first project

Comment: Could you provide some code? What do you have already, what doesn't work etc.…

Answer (score 0):

I've actually not used Devise before, however assuming you have a befor_filter on your controller to route to Devise authentication, you could possibly do something like:

```
skip_before_filter :authenticate_with_devise if user_answered_question_correctly?
```

Answer (score 0):

this gem has a security_questionable feature which would do the trick, amongst other things https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension

Comment: Have you ever tried this package? I haven't been able to get the security_questionable feature to work. I get "Can't mass-assign protected attributes" when I try to create the questions.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to override `Devise` for this.

1. make your own `forget_password` routes:

in `routes.rb`:

```
get "forgot_password" => "passwords#forgot"
get "forgot_password/verify_question" => "passwords#verify_question"
post "forgot_password/verify_answer" => "passwords#verify_answer"
post "forgot_password/reset_password" => "passwords#reset"
```

2. Create `app/controller/passwords_controller.rb` and fill out logic you want via forms / render.
3. Create views.
4. Change `forgot password` link to your own.
5. Profit